# Spring Security 5 + Thymeleaf + WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I'm using the `org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5` package in a WebFlux project but unfortunately it's not working. Both `sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"` and `sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"` gives back false, since none of the content is rendered (no error in the logs).

I've also added:

```
@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
    return new SpringSecurityDialect();
}
```

With the import `org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;` but that didn't help either. What am I missing here? Is Spring Security 5 / WebFlux not yet supported?

Comment: Tested Spring security 5 dialect is working with Thymeleaf. There is no need to initiate a bean for springsecuritydialect. You might need to include more of your configuration as well as how you render your content. Could be something else instead of spring security issue.

Comment: @Chris actually there is literally no other configuration, only Spring Boot 2.1 + sec:authorize on a div tag. I've tested the exact same stuff without WebFlux and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Spring Boot 6 this needs a configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun webFluxSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http.anonymous {
            Customizer.withDefaults<AnonymousSpec>()
        } // more config
        .build()
    }
}
```

With the Customizer a org.springframework.security.config.Customizer, and
the AnonymousSpec a org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity.AnonymousSpec